# Having trouble getting UIImage from image NSURL

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

Having problem getting image from the image URL. Is this the right way? Need help. Thanks in advance

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage * chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: There is no description of the error. No information of any results of debugging such as the first line that is in error. -1.

Comment: what does that mean `UIImage * chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]`

Comment: I had to use a c++ library which needs the image's URL to be attached. In this way, I will have to get the url of the image, and then retrieve the image by the url.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
self.image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Be aware that info may not contain an entry for edited image;

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand what way you mentioned. My problem is I had to use a c++ library which needs the image's URL to be attached. In this way, I will have to get the url of the image, and then retrieve the image by the url.

Comment: The key you have chosen to use (UIIMmagePickerControllerEditedImage] returns a value of UIImage, not an NSURL. There are other keys returned in info that are NSStrings which can be used to construct NSURL, but not for the edited version of the image. You can either use the url of the original image with UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL, or using your current key, use ALAssetsLibary to write it to your library. Your question is unclear.